# error in shellscript while using psql command

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, sh, psql

hi guys I am trying to get data from psql using shellscript
here are my command which is working fine

```
PGPASSWORD=nifi psql -U nifi -d MPT_BI -h 10.10.101.10
\copy (select * from dwctr.tcmpt_usage_cellid_daily where stat_date='20200502' limit 10) TO '/home/bi_it/csv_export/gp_export/dwctr.tcmpt_usage_cellid_dailny_20200502.csv' CSV DELIMITER '^'
\q
```

but when I am tryiyng to automate using shell i am getting error here is my shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
dir='/home/bi_it/csv_export/gp_export'
cd $dir
PGPASSWORD=nifi psql -U nifi -d MPT_BI -h 10.10.101.10
    \copy (select * from dwctr.tcmpt_usage_cellid_daily where stat_date='20200502' limit 10) TO '/home/bi_it/csv_export/gp_export/dwctr.tcmpt_usage_cellid_dailny_20200502.csv' CSV DELIMITER '^'
    \q
```

error

```
./newgp.sh: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `select'
./newgp.sh: line 6: `\copy (select * from dwctr.tcmpt_usage_cellid_daily where stat_date='20200502' limit 10) TO '/home/bi_it/csv_export/gp_export/dwctr.tcmpt_usage_cellid_dailny_20200502.csv' CSV DELIMITER '^''
```

can any one help me with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a "here document":

```sh
#!/bin/bash
dir='/home/bi_it/csv_export/gp_export'
cd "$dir"
PGPASSWORD=nifi psql -U nifi -d MPT_BI -h 10.10.101.10 <<EOF
\copy (select * from dwctr.tcmpt_usage_cellid_daily where stat_date='20200502' limit 10) TO '/home/bi_it/csv_export/gp_export/dwctr.tcmpt_usage_cellid_dailny_20200502.csv' CSV DELIMITER '^'
\q
EOF
```

Everything up to the final `EOF` will become the standard input for `psql`.